# Audio and video from MKV file getting out of sync in multiple media players

Tags: audio, video, sync, vlc-media-player, matroska

I noticed an issue while playing MKV files on my HP laptop. After about an hour or so, the audio starts to get out of sync with the video, and the delay becomes greater and greater. If i restart the video and seek to where i left, the syncing goes back to normal.

The MKV file itself is therefore flawless - i noticed this issue happening with multiple files - and also the video player is not to blame, as i tried both with Media Player Classic and VLC. As a potentially useful additional detail, i project my laptop onto an external TV when this happens.

What could cause this synchronization problem? Is it a performance issue? I keep my drivers and apps up-to-date.

Comment: If these are, er, "rips", then they could be badly muxed.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey i'm 99% sure the mkv files are flawless, i noticed this happening for 4 or 5 of them, completely unrelated. And when i restart them, the issue goes away.

Comment: Does that prove they are flawless?

Comment: I sometimes see issues if my puter if it's only just waking up as I start playback - the files are on HD which doesn't spin up immediately with the rest of the machine. This causes slight video hiccups & drops the video behind the audio. The 'fix' is one short tap back in time with any of the playback hot keys [VLC].

Comment: @MichaelHarvey if they were, wouldn't i notice the sync issue consistently, at the exact same timestamp? Besides, running the files on my desktop PC instead of my laptop works without a glitch.

Comment: Higher performance hardware (desktop PC) may be able to keep sync in a difficult file when a lesser machine cannot

Comment: This is my laptop model - https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c05463344. At these specs, it should run an mkv file at 1080p without a problem, even on 2 screens at once (the laptop screen and the TV screen).

Comment: What are the chances that the delay is introduced by the HDMI cable? I also noticed many small green dots in the blank portions of the picture, looks like noise.